# LockService or JobLockService To Lock Node

Tags: alfresco

What is the difference between LockService and JobLockService in the alfresco and where i can use both of them in case i have a node already exist represents the sequence of other nodes created, and that node must be locked before getNextSequence() ?

as example:

```java
Node sequenceNode = getSequenceNode();
LockService(sequenceNode);
Node aNode = new Node(new NodeRef(...));
Map<QName,serialzable> props = new HashMap<QName,Serializable>();
props.put(...,sequenceNode.getNextSequence()); 
nodeService.setProperty(..,..,..,props);
```

Now, is LockService enough for this knowing the sequenceNode not editable by alfresco web client, only will be edit by this line of code.

you replies are highly appreciated.
Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series Co.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: Use the LockService and be happy, it's enough for you in this case.

`LockService` is intended to acquire locks on specific nodes, while `JobLockService` is used to handle concurrency on specific tasks. More specifically:

- you use the `LockService` whenever you want exclusive access on a specific node or a set of nodes. You have to specify which nodes you want to lock and which [type of lock](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/lock/LockType.html) you want to apply. Once you gained the lock on one or more nodes the system will inhibit other users from accessing such nodes, and will keep doing so until you remove the lock or it expires
- you use the `JobLockService` when you need specific tasks to be executed only once at a time (e.g. to avoid concurrency runs). Locks handled by this service are not bound to specific nodes, and are identified by QNames. As a result, `JobLockService` doesn't prevent any node from being accessed or modified, but rather inhibit other threads or external applications from executing the same task (provided they first try to acquire the same lock). Say you have several remote systems that access the repository. The `JobLockService` allows you to force serial execution of the same taks on the whole network of systems.

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a node holding a sequence number or something similar, and you need the `getNextSequence` to be reliably providing the next identifier. While you could use both services here, since the critical operation is really bound to a single node (the one holding the sequence), I would rather use the `LockService` here.

Comment: Can you give me more examples about JobLockService, till i'm confusing

Comment: Is possible to use JobLockService to replace LockService as example JobLockService.getLock(QName.createQName(....),...); and that will be identical to the LockService.

Comment: What About Clustered Environment ?